# jquery next and previous button in date picker not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery datepicker. In that i'm facing a problem. When the date picker pop ups, I clicked the previous and next button in the date picker but it didn't work. There is a select dropdown field behind the popup. So when I click the next or previous button the dropdown options are viewed. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8devrvv8/)

```
Here if we remove the select the next and previous button gets clicked.
```

Help can be useful.

Comment: can you add the right fiddle

Comment: @Geeky I have added the fiddle.

Comment: When the footer is present the picker gets hidden. How can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the the z-index:

```
.ui-select .ui-btn select{z-index:1 !important}
```

It will work

Comment: its a bad practice to use CSS specificity `!important`, instead if  you create a css selector which is more specific to the element, then it would  automatically take preference.

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown is placed at top of the view stack since its `z-index = 2` compared to the datepicker's `z-index`, which is set to 1.

even though you never added the `z-index` to any of the elements on your page, the jquery plugin has added these properties while rendering.

so change the `z-index` of the select dropdown to 0 & add a specific CSS selector as shown below.

**CSS code:**

```
.container .main select {
   z-index:0;
}
```

[Working demo @ jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8devrvv8/4/)

*Note: I have added the css selector which targets the element more precisely, the same can be achived by using CSS specificity `!important`, but its a bad practice to use that. using CSS specificity alters the CSS precedence structure*

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue of depth(z-index) of elements. Your select box is above the datepicker, so when you click on date picker it actually clicked select box. Just try this

CSS

```
#select-4-button{
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

All the best :)